# window.location.assign doesn't continue

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to delete a record in my database.

HTML

```
<a href="" onclick="return delUnit('grams');">DELETE</a>
```

JS

```
function delUnit(unit)
    {
    var r=window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this unit?");
    if (r==true)
      {
        //window.alert(val); I used alert to see if val was containing the word grams
        window.location.assign("deleteunit.php?val="+unit);
        return false;
      }
    }
```

PHP

```
$val = $_GET['val'];
mysql_query("DELETE FROM setuptb WHERE val='$val' AND category='UNIT'");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) What does "doesn't continue" mean?

Comment: (Side note: Using a GET to modify server state is an anti-pattern. GET is supposed to be idempotent.)

Comment: More problems with the code: `mysql_*` is deprecated, use `mysqli` instead. This code is **vulnerable to SQL injections**. Please use prepared statements instead!

Answer (score 2):

After window.location.assign() please add return false;
like this

```
window.location.assign("deleteunit.php?val="+unit);
return false;
```

Comment: It works. I also added return before calling the function onclick